# How to create isolines in 3D for VTK?

Tags: c++, 3d, vtk

Is there a way of visualising isolines in 3D space (x, y and z)?

I am basically trying to show the flow of some points based off the velocities of these points and the example on the VTK website only does this in 2D (http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/LabelContours) and I don't know how to adapt this.  I have tried replacing the plane variable with a 3D glyph but I am getting a lot of errors and nothing appears in the render window

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if what you want is an isoline. Because an isoline is defined on a scalar field, which means one attribute at each point. Since you are talking about velocity of points, it seems to me you are dealing with a vector field. In that case, you should not create an isoline, but a *streamline* instead. Take a look at [this](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/StreamLines) example, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

the vtkContourFilter class works for both 2D and 3D. there is an example [here](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Examples/VisualizationAlgorithms/Python/VisQuad.py).